# calculate xor expression using DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, datatable, xor

I want to calculate a logical expression like `(true xor false)` I used DataTable but it dose not support `xor`. How can I calculate `xor` expressions?

```
System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
var result = table.Compute("( False xor True) ", "");
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but are you asking about XOR operator (^) in C#?

Comment: Indeed, the question at the moment is really unclear - at least I certainly don't understand what you're asking. Are you actually asking about expressing the logic in C#, or trying to parse a *string* containing text "(true And (false) [etc])" and evaluating it? (I note that your tags include "datatable" but there's nothing referencing that in the body of the question...)

Comment: I want to calculate the result of  this expression`(true And (false) xor(true) [etc])` . for example create a method that get this string and return the result

Comment: ah, you're trying to parse a string containing a C# expression.

Comment: yeh, I found `System.Data.DataTable table` but it dose not support `xor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse a string containing a C# logical expression. There are multiple ways of doing it:

1. Since your logical expression only uses different combinations of **true**, **false**, **and**, **or** and **xor**, with parenthesis, you could roll out your own parser. Should be a pretty slim function.
2. If you're using this in the context of a `DataTable` as evident from the question tags, there is a built-in function called `Compute` that can take simple expressions and evaluate them for you. XOR is not available by default in the list of supported operators, but you could write an equivalent expression using **not equal to** operator (<>). Remmber **A ^ B** is equivalent to **(A <> B)** in the context of DataTable's boolean expresions.
3. You could use Roslyn's built-in capabilities and parse and evaluate literally any C# expression at runtime.

Comment: can make a example for DataTable that calculate `Xor` expression

Comment: thanks for Answer but  second solution need some hard code to find closed parentheses and .... see this example:`(A and B)xor B And (A And B)`. third solution support 'Xor' directly?can send some reference?

Comment: I know in `DataTable` equal  can implement with `=`. DO you know what is the ‍not equal in `DataTable`? this can help to implement `xor`